# Qt QML for Android and iOS change colors Systemwide

Tags: qt, colors, controls, qml

I am trying to write a small app that has dark background.
To make life easier i make use of Qt quick controls.

For example the ToolButton.
When not-pressed the ToolButton has a black font so it is NOT visible on my dark background.

Reading other posts it seems (although hard to believe) that you can NOT set the text color (or other colors for that matter) for ToolButton or many other of the Qt quick controls.
The solution suggested is complete copy / paste recoding of those elements and / or the styles.
This sounds very dim of Qt / Digia and its hard to believe as the FIRST thing you want to "customize" is the colors (fore- back- text- active- inactive and so on...).

So is there any other way of app-wide change of those colors ?
In Qt widgets i would modify the QApplication::QPallette and things are done in a few lines.

Please help me out !

Nils

Comment: I can understand that it's frustrating when it's not clear how to do something, but does calling the developers who write this code "very dim" really help your question receive decent responses?

Comment: I did call the Qt / Digia way-of-doing-this dim, and believe me dim is a sensitive word IF they did it the way it seems. See my comments below if you have to add anything useful for the task. Don't get me wrong: We Developers can produce pathetic code but MOSTLY its company policy that forces us to do that (time pressure, changing specs, whatever). So to stress that: I did not want to insult the Digia Developers but MAYBE the way the controls are "forced" into the release. Prove me wrong and show me a good way to solve my problem, that would be great. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually try? Where did you read that it was not possible? I've not done much with palettes, but searching "palette qt 5.2" gave me [SystemPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html) as the second result, and it's been around since Qt 4.7. The properties are read-only, so the intention must be that you set the palette in C++.

A "complete copy/paste" of the controls/styles is not necessary, even without using `SystemPalette`:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "#444"

    ToolButton {
        text: "Button"
        style: ButtonStyle {
            label: Text {
                color: "red"
                text: control.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to reuse a style for several controls, just create a component out of it, either as a property or in its own QML file.

Comment: Hello, to cite you : "Did you actually try?". your proposal sadly does not work (and yes i tried that). If you do that the *complete* style is overwritten and you end up with a no-features button with red text. Thats why i said that an elaborate workaround is to copy / paste the original style and add the color directive. But thats not good and if thats needed this code is a piece of cr*p. Hmm, the Digia Developer at the mobile Roadshow sortof hinted that the whole Qt Control stuff is done with "hot needle" and i guess thats one of the results. Maybe there is a SMART workaround. anyone ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about your Palette comment. If you look at my initial question i am (sort-of) aware of the System Palette. I tried it but it failed (for QML, NOT for Qt widgets ! Can you provide a few lines that work with QML ? What i did was to get the QApplication::palette, to modify Active color group for "ButtonText" and to write it back. That had no effect on the QML Buttontext. Please let me know if you know better.

Comment: Whoa, all this using Qt 5.3 Beta but i don't think its better in previous versions...

Comment: Just to clarify: when you create a `ButtonStyle` object, you don't override anything. It's when you override specific style components that you start losing stuff. It might help if you add a compilable example of what you tried with `QPalette` so that we can see exactly what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Hello ! I just tried your code again, this time on Desktop. I was using QML for an iOS app and there i saw the "override all" behavior... On Desktop it "nearly" works (The text alignment is a bit off, whoever...). Did you ever try this on iOS or Android ? Maybe its just faulty on mobile...

Comment: No, sorry, just Windows 7.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be partially faulty on iOS. after changing the font color the way you suggested the button looked awful (ams style as on desktop, bad background). I added a section to set the background opacity to 0.0 and now it behaves okay. So somehow it now works for me, on Desktop it really behaves nice as it should be :-) So no "dimness" except me only trying it on iOS... Thank you